# Relacionamento de tabelas (API Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Estou criando uma API em PHP utilizando Laravel, porém não consegui fazer o relacionamento entre duas tabelas.

> Tabela Usuário(LoginUsers)>Comportamento de Usuário(Behaviors)

. Já criei o GET do LoginUser e do Behavior de forma separada, porém gostaria de que quando eu fizesse uma requisição do usuário (LoginUser) trazer os comportamentos dele(Behavior), e não só do usuário como está sendo feito hoje. A tabela Behaviors, possui a `fk login_user_id`. Alguém consegue me ajudar? Imagino que seja no Controller, mas não to sabendo fazer.

```
/

    /Model: LoginUser
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class LoginUser extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = ["status_id","access_group_id","first_name","last_name","email","password","agreement","ip_user","timezone"];

    public function getResults($login_user_id)
    {
        return $this->select(
                        'status_id',
                        'access_group_id',
                        'login_user_id',
                        'first_name',
                        'last_name'
                    )
                    ->where('login_user_id','=',"{$login_user_id}")
                    ->get();
    }

    public function Behaviors(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Behavior','login_user_id');
    }

//Controller: LoginUserController
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\LoginUser;

class LoginUserController extends Controller
{



    private $loginuser;

    public function __construct(LoginUser $loginuser)
    {
        $this->loginuser = $loginuser;
    }

    public function show(LoginUser $loginuser, Request $request)
    {
        $loginusers = $this->loginuser->getResults($request->login_user_id);
        return response()->json($loginusers);
    }



    }

}


//Model: Behavior

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Behavior extends Model
{
    //protected $fillable = [];

    public function getResults($login_user_id)
    {

        if(!$login_user_id)
            return $this->get();

        return $this->select(
                        'behavior_id',
                        'behaviors.key_behavior_id',
                        'lkp_key_behaviors.key_behavior',
                        'login_user_id'
                    )
                    ->join('lkp_key_behaviors','behaviors.key_behavior_id','=','lkp_key_behaviors.key_behavior_id')
                    ->where('login_user_id','=',"{$login_user_id}")
                    ->get();
    }

    public function LkpKeyBehaviors(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LkpKeyBehavior','key_behavior_id');
    }

    public function LoginUsers(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LoginUser','login_user_id');
    }
}
Controller: behaviorController

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Behavior;

class BehaviorController extends Controller
{

    private $behavior;

    public function __construct(Behavior $behavior)
    {
        $this->behavior = $behavior;
    }

    public function index(Behavior $behavior, Request $request)
    {
        $behaviors = $this->behavior->getResults($request->login_user_id);
        return response()->json($behaviors);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,
Quando você retorna um objeto com os registros de LoginUsers, se seu relacionamento está bem feito, voce pode usar algo assim:

```
$loginusers[0]->behavior
```

E eu particulamente usaria as funções nativas do Eloquent para as queries ao invés de fazer esses selects nos models. 
Exemplo:
Ao invés de adicionar o método **GetResults**, voce pode fazer isso:

```
loginusers = $this->loginuser::where('login_user_id',$request->login_user_id)->get();
```

Aqui explica mais:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-models